# Find non-diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $B^TAB$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, matrix-equations, math-software

Here $B^T$ denotes the transpose of $B$.

$A$ and $B$ are invertible $3\times 3$ matrices with integer entries.

$A$ is symmetric positive definite with at most two zero entries.

We want the determinants of both $A$ and $B$ be as small as possible (in terms of absolute value)

For a fixed matrix $A$, we want to find all matrices $B$ with small determinants, preferably less than 10, if they exist.

Comment: Clarify what you are looking for in this question please

Comment: I give an example of such kind of pairs $A$ and $B$ in the comments. It is $2 \times 2$ case though.

Answer (score 1):

two completely different questions.........

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & -1  \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You should be aware that, for any symmetric matrix $A$ of integers, there is a ***rational*** matrix $B$ of determinant $\pm 1$ such that $B^T A B$ is diagonal. See [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

If, as appears, you are writing a computer program to solve the second question: it is more difficult than you think. I suggest that you solve it completely for the 2 by 2 case; I guess this means a working program. You will be able to find numerous references on equivalence of binary quadratic forms over the rationals and over the integers. [For the three by three case, start with my introduction](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments.  I forgot to add the requirement that $detB > 1$,

Comment: @Drew in the 3 by 3 case that does not matter at all, since negating $B$ negates its determinant in odd dimension. Still, I do not really know, given how complicated this task actually is, how to advise you. Can you do the 2 by 2 case?

Answer (score 0):

If A is a symmetric positive definite matrix then $B^TAB$ is a diagonal matrix iff B is an orthogonal matrix i.e. $B^T=B^{-1}$. If $\exists$ such a matrix $B$ then $B^TAB=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. And the columns of $B$ are the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$. So to find the $B$ s.t. $det(B)<10$ you will need to find the eigenvectors of A.

Comment: $B$ is not necessarily orthogonal. We need all the entries to be integers.

Comment: You can always multiply the eigenvectors by some scalar such that all the entries are integers.

Comment: You will need $B$ to be orthogonal for $B^TAB=diag$ to hold. Infact this only holds because A is positive definite and symmetric.

Comment: If $A=\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 5
\end{array}
\right) $  and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -2 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$